# Automatic file transfer between two IIS servers

Tags: file, iis, web-applications

In a scenario within our company, we have two web applications published on different IIS servers. One of them is the joined to the company domain and hosts the internal users' web application while the other is not joined to the domain and hosts the external users' web application. In a special scenario, external users are required to upload a file to the server and internal users need to access that files. What is the best way to store these files and synchronize them?

I think about the third server as a file server which hosts these files? But, how we can do it?

There are several constraints which are imposed by security team:
1- do not use third party software
2- do not use folder sharing solution
3- use standard features on IIS

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't provide any in-built solutions for sharing files. You can however use FTPS to ease your solution. Here is one way to solve the problem

1. Implement file-upload in the external web app which allows the users to upload files. You can either write a file-upload control or simply use **FTPS**.
2. You can create a **FTPS** site on the internal facing server which points to the above location

However, for the above to work you will need to have a common access to the files.

- You can create a file server in the domain which is accessible only to the non-domain joined server.
- You can create a internal facing file server and then have mechanism to sync the files from the external facing server. There is a freeware from Microsoft which allows you to do this. [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155)
- Write an application or service which does the file sync periodically from the source to destination.